# How to write If conditions in regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the amount from the following string:

> Delivery Charge    $2
>   Promo - (FIRST)    ($4)
>    $7
>   New  Coins earned    $5
>   Issued on behalf of
>   .......................

The line "New Coins earned $5" might not be present sometime. I am willing to capture the Amount paid which is "7" in this case. I tried with  `\.?\s*\n*([\d.,]+)\s*\n*Issued\s*\n*on` but this will only capture the amount if "New Coins earned $5" is not present in the document. I read about if else conditions and positive-lookahead. However, couldn't make this working. Any suggestions on how to capture?

Comment: Why not just `^\$(\d+)$`? See https://regex101.com/r/nFsoiz/1

Comment: Else, how can you describe the context to match? Is the value you want always on a separate line? Try `^\$(\d[\d.,]*)[\r\n]*(?:.*[\r\n]+)*Issued\s+on`, too ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/nFsoiz/2)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works only if my amount is less than $1000. Above $1000, it's written as $1,000 and also amount may be $5.6

Comment: Then `^\$(\d[\d,.]*)$`? Is it always preceded with `$` and on a separate line?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it is always preceded with $ on separate line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but I don't need to capture $7, I need only 7

Comment: It’s unclear what you want to capture in each case (and, to be honest, what the different cases look like).

Comment: It is not a problem if you can access the capturing group. What is the programming language? `7` is in Group 1.

Comment: I want to capture the total amount (in this case 7). One scenario is given above and in another scenario, "New coins earned $5" is missing. Also, The amount is always followed by $ and is on separate line.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is just a practice. However, I am trying to implement in Python in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value you need is always preceded with `$` on a separate line you may use

```
\$(\d[\d,.]*)[\n\r]+(?:.*[\r\n]+){0,2}Issued\s+on\b
```

The value you need is in Group 1.

**Details**

- `\$` - a `$` char
- `(\d[\d,.]*)` - Group 1: a digit followed with any 0+ digits, `,` or `.` chars
- `[\n\r]+` - 1 or more CR or LF symbols
- `(?:.*[\r\n]+){0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 repetitions of 0+ chars other  than  linebreak chars followed with 1+ LF/CR symbols
- `Issued\s+on\b` - `Issued`, 1+ whitespaces, `on` as a whole word (as `\b` is a word boundary).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nFsoiz/4).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/noSBBQ):

```
import re
rx = r"\$(\d[\d,.]*)[\n\r]+(?:.*[\r\n]+){0,2}Issued\s+on\b"
s = "Delivery Charge $2\nPromo - (FIRST) ($4)\n$1,000.55\nNew Coins earned $5\nIssued on behalf of ......................."
match = re.search(rx, s, re.M)
if match:
    print(match.group(1)) # -> 1,000.55
```

Comment: The document shown in the question is the receipt of a company. I am downloading the HTML of the receipt and removing the HTML tags to show only texts. So, there might be spaces and new lines in between. For example : $7 might be written after few whitespaces and two lines below the Promo. That is why I wrote this regular expression `\.?\s*\n*([\d.,]+)\s*\n*Issued\s*\n*on`

Comment: @SuloveBista Ok, 1 or 2 lines may come before `Issued on`? I have edited the solution to meet these requirements.  I hope they are final

Comment: Yes. 1 or 2 lines may come before the amount as well as after the amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like `(?(?=regex)then|else)`, but notice that `(?=)` is lookahead and have zero length, so your then condition must match expression in brackets too.

You also can make more complex expressions in a way
`(?(?=condition)(then1|then2|then3)|(else1|else2|else3))`
Where `then1, then2, then3` sorted in descending priority order, because first matching "then" condition will skip all others.

You can look for more info [here](https://regular-expressions.mobi/conditional.html?wlr=1)